# How to drag and drop element if only item do not exist in Array - React DND ES6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-dnd

I am working on a project that involves React DND ES6. I want to drag elements from the lest panel and drop them in respective boxes in right.

I have done this by dragging the element from left panel and implementing in to an Array. But the problem here is same item is able to add in to the array as follows.

I want to make it such that If item is already dragged to a particular box, dragging again that item from left panel and drop in correct box should not work. In a situation like that it should display alert box saying like ‘Item _name’ is already dragged to the ‘box_name’.

I tried achieve this adding following code before setBins method. But was not successful.

```
 if (!lastDroppedItem.includes(item)){  setBins(
         update(bins, {
          [index]: {
            lastDroppedItem: {
                          $push: [item],   
            },
          },
        })       
      )
    },
    [droppedBoxNames , bins],   )
```

Please find my codes in codesandbox here: - https://codesandbox.io/s/reactdndapp-2vz82

Please do help. Thank You.

Comment: Hi Ajeeth Shah. I edited my codes. Could you please have a look now?

Comment: please could you set up your code in codesandbox? this will be very easy to help provide a solution.

Comment: Hi Rotmi-best. Thanks I edited the question. Please find the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/reactdndapp-2vz82

Comment: @ChamaniShiranthika Please check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-merkle-0fx8o?file=/src/example.jsx) I created. It doesn't allow duplicates now. You can check `alert` and `console logs` there.

Comment: Thank you @Ajeet Shah, But here the alert comes when an item is dragged and dropped twice to ANY bin. I want it as when dragged and dropped only to SAME bin. That means the item which was drag and drop to Bin 1 at first, is rejected by Bin 1 when put again, But it should be able to put to another bin, say Bin 2.

Comment: @ChamaniShiranthika Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-merkle-0fx8o?file=/src/example.jsx). Added a new property `droppedItems` for each bin. I hope it works for you.

Comment: @AjeetShah Thank you very much. This is clear and it's exactly what I was looking for. I understand it now.  Thanks You for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one more property - `droppedItems` for each bin which holds all the dropped items so far, an example:

```
{
  dname: 'BIN 1',
  accepts: [ItemTypes.BOOK, ItemTypes.BOTTLE, ItemTypes.FOOD],
  lastDroppedItem: {},
  droppedItems: [],
},
```

And check if the item is already in bin:

```
function isBoxAlreadyInBin(bins, index, name) {
  const droppedItems = bins[index].droppedItems || [];
  return droppedItems.some(item => item.name === name);
}

const handleDrop = useCallback(
(index, item) => {
  const { name } = item;

  setDroppedBoxNames(
    update(droppedBoxNames, name ? { $push: [name] } : { $push: [] })
  );

  if (isBoxAlreadyInBin(bins, index, name)) {
    alert(`${name} already in bin ${index}`);
  } else {
    setBins(
      update(bins, {
        [index]: {
          lastDroppedItem: {
            $set: item
          },
          droppedItems: {
            $push: [item]
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
},
[droppedBoxNames, bins]
);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do search the array if an instance of the object you are about to drop exists in the bin first before you update it by calling the setBin method, otherwise you can ignore or trigger a notification.

Here I used the javascript array `find` method to check if a similar object exists in the bin.

```js
if (!bins[index].lastDroppedItem.find(x => x.name === item.name)) {
    setBins(
        update(bins, {
            [index]: {
              lastDroppedItem: {
                $push: [item]
              }
            }
        })
    );
}
```